# Looping in powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have written a script that's purpose is to list all files in a directory from a list of computers that are imported from a .txt file and it will compress the files to a network path. I am not sure if I have written it correctly, hoping you can look at it and let me know if there is a better way.

Script looks like this:

```
$destination = \\networkpath

$machines = (Get-Content "\\networkpath\machines.txt")

foreach ($machine in $machines) { $sourcefiles = gci "\\$machine\C$\localpath" }

foreach ($sourcefile in $sourcefiles) { 
    Compress-Archive -Path "\\$machine\C$\localpath" -Destinationpath "$Destination\$Sourcefile.zip" -CompresionLevel Optimal -Verbose }
```

The script works for one machine (the last one in the text file) so it looks like it just isn't looping, probably because of this double foreach loop I am using. I tried piping the output of $sourcefiles to a compress-archive but this doesn't zip the files individually.

Any ideas where I went wrong here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you loop through here,

```
foreach ($machine in $machines) { $sourcefiles = gci "\\$machine\C$\localpath" }
```

`$sourcefiles` will Always be the last machine's sourceFiles. You will need to keep track of source files for each of the machine and run through those files per that machine. Loop through the machines once and run both commands in one loop.

Comment: Got it, can you think of a way I could do this without adding a line for each machine in the script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an inner loop rather than a separate loop.
That way, you can access the current value of `$machine` while iterating the files.

```
$destination = "\\networkpath"

$machines = (Get-Content "\\networkpath\machines.txt")

foreach ($machine in $machines) {
        $SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path  "\\$machine\C$\localpath"
        Foreach ($SourceFile in $SourceFiles ) {
                Compress-Archive -Path "\\$machine\C$\localpath" -Destinationpath "$Destination\$Sourcefile.zip" -CompresionLevel Optimal -Verbose 
        }
}
```